# remove dictionary from list in pandas colum

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have dataframe where one of the columns is a list of dictionaries that is stored as a string like so:

```
name age misc
Jim  44  "[{"value":3,"type":"cars"},{"value":1,"type":"pets"},{"value":13,"type":"shoes"}]"
Bob  25  "[{"value":3,"type":"siblings"},{"value":1,"type":"pets"}]"
Sue  55  "[]"
```

I want to get to this where each type becomes it's own column with the corresponding values:

```
name age cars pets shoes siblings
Jim  44  3    1    13    0
Bob  25  0    1    0     3
Sue  55  0    0    0     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**:  Convert the string 'list' column to actual lists:

```
from ast import literal_eval 

df['misc'] = [literal_eval(r) for r in df.misc]
```

**Step 2**:  Loop through each dictionary to get the 'values' (e.g. cars, pets, shoes, etc.).  Add a column to the DataFrame for each unique value.

```
sublists = [[d.get('type') for d in cell] for cell in df.misc]
cols = list(set([item for sublist in sublists for item in sublist]))
for c in cols:
    df[c] = 0
```

**Step 3**:  Create a dictionary which gets the value for each type (this assumes that there is not more than one type for a given list of dictionaries in the row).  Then enumerate through these value counts and assign the result back to the DataFrame:

```
value_counts = [{d.get('type'): d.get('value') for d in cell} for cell in df.misc]
for n, row in enumerate(value_counts):
if row:
    items, values = zip(*row.items())
    df.loc[df.index[n], items] = values

del df['misc']

>>> df
  name  age  cars  shoes  pets  siblings
0  Jim   44     3     13     1         0
1  Bob   25     0      0     1         3
2  Sue   55     0      0     0         0
```

Comment: This seems promising, the issue is that I'm now finding that each of those are actually strings so it's actually like this: `"[{"value":3,"type":"cars"},{"value":1,"type":"pets"},{"value":13,"type":"shoes"}]"`

Comment: You can convert it back to a list using literal_eval:  from ast import literal_eval  df['misc'] = [literal_eval(r) for r in df.misc]

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid creating a DataFrame with a column whose values are a list of
dicts. But to help you do that we would need to understand the source of the
data which is being used to build the current DataFrame.

Given the current DataFrame, however, you could transform it into the desired
DataFrame by using `df['misc'].apply(func)` to call a function, `func`, on each
value in `df['misc']`.

If you arrange for this function to return a Series, then
`df['misc'].apply(func)` will return a DataFrame whose columns correspond to the index of the Series. For example,

```
def func(x):
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x))
        result = pd.Series(df['value'].values, index=df['type'])
    except KeyError:
        result = pd.Series()
    return result

attributes = df['misc'].apply(func)
print(attributes)
```

yields

```
   cars  pets  shoes  siblings
0     3     1     13       NaN
1   NaN     1    NaN         3
2   NaN   NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Now we can replace the NaNs with 0:

```
attributes = attributes.fillna(0)
```

remove the `misc` column from `df`:

```
del df['misc']
```

and build the desired DataFrame by concatenating `df` with `attributes`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, attributes], axis=1)
```

---

Putting it all together,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [('Jim', 44, '''[{"value":3,"type":"cars"},{"value":1,"type":"pets"}, {"value":13,"type":"shoes"}]'''),
     ('Bob', 25, '[{"value":3,"type":"siblings"},{"value":1,"type":"pets"}]'),
     ('Sue', 55, '[]')],
    columns=['name', 'age', 'misc'])

def func(x):
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x))
        result = pd.Series(df['value'].values, index=df['type'])
    except KeyError:
        result = pd.Series()
    return result

attributes = df['misc'].apply(func)
attributes = attributes.fillna(0)
del df['misc']
df = pd.concat([df, attributes], axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
  name  age  cars  pets  shoes  siblings
0  Jim   44     3     1     13         0
1  Bob   25     0     1      0         3
2  Sue   55     0     0      0         0
```

Comment: That works perfectly but when I try it on my set (that's in the same format) I get an error: `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: It sounds like the misc column contains *strings*. It would really be better to build the desired DataFrame correctly from the raw data instead of  bending over backwards to fix the current DataFrame, but if you must, then you can convert the string to a list of dicts using `ast.literal_eval`. I've edited the post to show how.

Answer (score 0):

I would really read up in here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/api.html#dataframe. Also the source of your data must really be all over the place, I would work first on reformatting that. Since you didn't supply the original source of the data itself, here is a simple example though of creating a DataFrame that you're looking for assuming a more structured data source:

```
>>> data = {'Bob':{'age':25, 'pets':1, 'siblings':3}, 'Jim':{'age':44, 'cars':3, 'pets': 1, 'shoes': 13}}
>>> pd.DataFrame(data).T.fillna(0)

     age  cars  pets  shoes  siblings
Bob   25     0     1      0         3
Jim   44     3     1     13         0
```